# Navigate the default browser to a new URL in the same tab

Tags: browser, vb6

My program can open a URL in the default browser. It opens the default browser if its not already opened and navigate the tab to sent URL. I am using following code:

```
opened = ShellExecuteA(0, "Open", URL, Chr(32), vbNormalFocus, 1)
```

The problem is that this *always opens a new tab* after opening first tab. Instead  I would like it to refresh that first tab opened by my function.

I was wondering if it can be done by getting  browser's tab ID and then sending new URL to that tab if it is already openend so no new tab gets open with this call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you targeting a specific browser? If so, you'll probably just want to use that browser's automation interface, whatever it is. If you just want to use a "default browser", well there's no guarantee that it even has the concept of tabs, so it'd be hard to control specifically.

Comment: i want to use default browser. What if i want to use a specific browser like chrome what would be the solution for it in visual basic 6.0

Comment: For chrome, there is a command line switch to open the web page in a new browser window (which would then be the only tab on that window), see https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#new-window.  There doesn't appear to be a 'reuse tab' switch, though.